# MS Access simple SQL update query

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

With below code, I run the update on a specific table. The query completes without any problems (exception) but results are not updated in table. How is this even possible?

Table structure

[image]

Update query

```vb
 Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        cmd.CommandText = " UPDATE  [leadsonline_stores] SET [db_Path] = @db_Path,[Image_Path] = @Image_Path,[lo_Username] = @lo_Username,[lo_Password] = @lo_Password,[lo_Store] = @lo_Store,[Notes] = @Notes,[lo_Active] = @lo_Active WHERE [ID] = @ID "

        cmd.Connection = dbMain

        With cmd.Parameters
            .AddWithValue("@ID", leadsonline_stores_ID)
            .AddWithValue("@db_Path", txtDatabase.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Image_Path", txtPath.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@lo_Username", txtUsername.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@lo_Password", txtPassword.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@lo_Store", txtStoreId.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@Notes", txtDescription.Text)
            .AddWithValue("@lo_Active", IIf(IsNothing(chkActive.EditValue), DBNull.Value, chkActive.EditValue))
        End With

        Try

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error while changing data", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            dbMain.Close()
            Return False
        End Try
```

Before update :

[image]

Debugger info :
[image]

What am i missing here.

Comment: `rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`  If the result is non zero, it did update the DB.  Is the db part of the project or do you specify a path in the connection string?

Comment: Your parameters look out of order - with oleDB / MS-Access you need to supply them in the exact same order as they appear in the SQL.  Also, `AddWithValue` is a bad idea, use `.Add(string, dbtype).value = ...`  And of course, storing passwords as plain text is also a very bad idea

Comment: @Plutonix `rows = 0` . Exact same order means order of fields in table ? I use connection string from another path.

Comment: Perhaps the filter on your query can find no matching rows to update.

Comment: *exact same order as they appear in the SQL*

Comment: @STLDeveloper i did the screenshot of existing ID in table and also in executing mode im updating the correct ID

Comment: @Plutonix I dont understand. by my understanding they were already in exact same order except the id is on last position in where clause

Comment: correct.  **Therefore** you need to add the ID parameter **last**.  "except the id" means they are all off by one

Comment: So... your ID is out of order then. Move it to the end where you set your parameters so they are in order and re-execute. The names when you set parameters are ignored because OLEDB/Access is a big steaming pile of garbage.

Comment: @programerAnel - I don't see what you're talking about.  The image which you label "Debugger Info" doesn't show parameter values.

Comment: Dear god i refuse to believe what solved my issue. I could spent months by debugging and searching for a problem...

Comment: ...or you could visit MSDN where this is clearly documented

Comment: @STLDeveloper You have info before update ID : 6 db_Path : 123 .. ON debugger window you see im updating the id :  6 with new value

Comment: @Plutonix you are lucky if you have enough time to read those things on MSDN. I always use MS SQL for db storage this is probably first and last time i travel back in time to use access. Please post your comment as answer

Comment: ...and how much time did you spend wrestling with this because you *didnt* read the docs?  *Measure twice, cut once*